# How to display error above input with bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

I'm using [Bootstrap validator for bootstrap 3](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) and trying to display error messages above the input.

Here is the provided HTML code example:

```
<form role="form" data-toggle="validator">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

this works fine but I want to display the error like this:

```
<!-- display error -->
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
<!-- input -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail">
</div>
```

Am I missing something here, how to do it right?

or, is there another way to accomplish this task by using JavaScript? (if the first block of code is used, can I move the error above the input like the example of the 2nd code?)

Comment: Please add example code in jsfiddle

Comment: Put error block inside `form-group` div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the error inside the same parent div as the input. Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail">
</div>
```